# How to set PYTHONHASHSEED for jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.5

I am trying to set `PYTHONHASHSEED=0` to be able to reproduce my code. I know how to set it if using `python filename.py`, but I am using a .ipynb file. Is there any way I can set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` for my notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%env PYTHONHASHSEED=0` or `%env PYTHONHASHSEED 0` . (Use `%env` by itself to print out current environmental variables.)

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magic#magic-env

Answer (score 3):

Do note that setting `PYTHONHASHSEED` in this way will not help with reproducibility -- Python checks for the environment variable when it is invoked, and does not seem to use it at all after.

If you want to set `PYTHONHASHSEED` for a Jupyter notebook, you could try adding it to Jupyter's `kernel.json` (described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61953451/13692407).

Alternatively, if you are using Anaconda you could configure it to set the environmental variable every time you activate the Conda environment (described here: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables).