# Is there a way to set PYTHONHASHSEED for a Jupyter Notebook session?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables

I want to disable the [randomization of Python's *hash* function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). According to this thread ([Unable to see or modify value of PYTHONHASHSEED through a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538764/unable-to-see-or-modify-value-of-pythonhashseed-through-a-module)), setting PYTHONHASHSEED by setting `os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']` at runtime does not work. How can I set PYTHONHASHSEED to a fixed value when I run Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to modify the `kernel.json` and add the line `"env": {"PYTHONHASHSEED":"0"}`.
The file is located in your python-folder or virtual environment at:

```
[venv|python-folder]/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
```

kernel.json:

```
{
     "argv": [
      "python",
      "-m",
      "ipykernel_launcher",
      "-f",
      "{connection_file}"
     ],
     "display_name": "Python 3",
     "language": "python",
     "env": {"PYTHONHASHSEED":"0"}
}
```

That solves the issue for me.

Comment: For future reference, on mac with conda, I found it here: `/Users/[user]/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels`